# Reading a text file into an array, exploding delimiter, and displaying in a vertical list on a web page

Tags: php, arrays, explode

So far I have the code below but as a result, the only thing that is being displayed is the page heading. I am trying to read the text file below into an array:

```
pear|apple|strawberry|lime|elderberry|watermelon|orange|banana|fig|mango|plum
```

When displaying this text on a web page, I need to explode the "|" delimiter and display the fruits in a vertical list. Any help? Here is the code that I have in the body:

```
<h1>Sorted Fruits</h1>
<?php
$file = "Exercise5/exercise5.txt";
$FruitList = file($file);
$lines = explode("| ", $c);
foreach ( $lines as $l ) {
    echo $l;
    die();
}
?>
```

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Err there isn't any "code below"!

Comment: Remove the die() function.
It's terminating your script on the first iteration of your exploded array.

Comment: @adriancrepaz - I imagine the OP was attempting to debug with that `die()`. The problem appears to be putting a space, `"| "`, in the delimiter where there is not apparently one in the actual string to split.

Answer (score 2):

```
$fruits = "pear|apple|strawberry|lime|elderberry|watermelon|orange|banana|fig|mango|plum";
$fruitlist = implode('</li><li>', array_filter(explode('|', $fruits)));
$fruitlist = "
<ul>
  <li>$fruitlist</li>
</ul>
";
```

http://codepad.org/xJcrN1UG (w/example using `ucwords` to capitalize each term)

Or:

```
$fruits = "pear|apple|strawberry|lime|elderberry|watermelon|orange|banana|fig|mango|plum";
$fruitlist = str_replace('|', '</li><li>', $fruits);
$fruitlist = "
<ul>
  <li>$fruitlist</li>
</ul>
";
```

The former method removes empties with `array_filter()`, things like `pear||apple` that may occur.

Answer (score 0):

Easy task, but okay, I solve it for you.

```
$string = "pear|apple|strawberry|lime|elderberry|watermelon|orange|banana|fig|mango|plum" ;
$fruits = explode("|", $string) ;
foreach ($fruits as $fruit){
  echo $fruit . "<br/>" ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $string = 'pear|apple|strawberry|lime|elderberry|watermelon|orange|banana|fig|mango|plum';
  $fruits = explode("|", $string);
?>
<ul>
<?php foreach ($fruits as $fruit) : ?>
    <li><?= $fruit; ?></li></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```